# Are matrices $AB~BA$ similar? (where $A$ and $B$ are not necessary singular)

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the matrix $AB$ similar to $BA$, where $A$ and $B$ are not necessary singular?

Comment: Do you mean "not necessarily _nonsingular_" (in other words possibly singular)? Because if one of $A,B$ i nonsingular, then obviously $AB\sim BA$.

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ is similar to $BA$ if and only if $\mathrm{rank} (AB)^k=\mathrm{rank}(BA)^k$ for each $k=1,2,\cdots,n$

Answer (score 0):

No, you can find $AB$ with the image of $B$ contained in the kernel of $A$, so that $AB=0$, without the image of $A$ being contained in the kernel of $B$, so that $BA\neq0$. Apart from their dimensions (which are under control of the rank-nullity theorem), you can manipulate kernel and image of a linear map *independently*, by right-multiplication respectively left-multiplication by an invertible linear map; this freedom will allow you to easily construct an example of the above situation.

Comment: Apologies for answering and then closing the question.